# mouseclick action event performs in wrong way in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent

Here am using mouseClicked event to get data on the field while clicking on the table for that i used my code as below

```
scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void  mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            int rowIndex= table.getSelectedRow();
            DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            txt_Product_ID.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex,0).toString());
            txt_Product_Code.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex,1).toString());
            txt_Product_Name.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex,2).toString());
        }
    });
```

Here the problem is when i click on the row or column the data is not appearing on the corresponding fields but appearing when clicking on row or column and clicking on  the remaining space available on the table.so double time clicking only producing the result.please help me to solve my problem

Comment: You may need to translate the table's (view) row index into the the model's context

Comment: am new to java,so can you help me thanks a lot

Comment: The you should start with [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) have a demonstratable example, you're looking for `convertRowIndexToModel`

Comment: To get better help post [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
```

> Here the problem is when i click on the row or column the data is not appearing on the corresponding fields

Don't add the MouseListener to the scrollPane. The MouseListener should be added to the table, since that is the component you are clicking on.